# Aircrack-ng SVN error 1

Tags: compiling, svn

i've already downloaded aircrack-ng from the SVN repo and i'm trying to build it from source and this is what i get:

```
make -C src all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/chris/aircrack-ng/src'
gcc -g -W -Wall -O3 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REVISION=2363  -DCONFIG_LIBNL30 -I/usr/include/libnl3   -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-array-bounds -Iinclude  wpaclean.o osdep/radiotap/radiotap-parser.o -o wpaclean -Losdep -losdep -lnl-genl-3 -lnl-3  
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnl-genl-3
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [wpaclean] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/chris/aircrack-ng/src'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

i'm compiled it before but i did an upgraded clean install of linux mint 16 but now for some reason i'm missing something. any help would be great! thanks in advance!

Comment: linuxmint offtopic

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're missing the development libraries for libnl-genl-3. Issue this command:

`sudo apt-get install libnl-genl-3-dev`

That should fix it.

Comment: thanks a lot! that fixed it! i knew it was something simple that i was overlooking.

Comment: in case it fixes your problem, please consider marking the answer as accepted. :)