# Error on installing aircrack-ng "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnl-genl-3"

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, aircrack-ng

I am using 14.04. I followed [this post on installing Aircrack](/q/496585). As I enter the last command `sudo make install` I am getting this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnl-genl-3
```

Comment: @lakksmansritharan I think [that answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/391174) will solve this. Still, I suggest [edit]ing to clarify the significance of [tag:kali], or to remove that tag if you believe your question is completely unrelated to Kali Linux, and to tell what version of aircrack-ng you're trying to install, what download link you used,  and if you have the same problem with [1.2-rc2](http://download.aircrack-ng.org/aircrack-ng-1.2-rc2.tar.gz). As this now seems on-topic, I'm hoping we can reopen this and merge the answer to [that off-topic question](https://askubuntu.com/q/391163) here.

Comment: you probably need to at least install the dev package but nothing  will be lost by installing all three `sudo apt-get install libnl-genl-3-200 libnl-genl-3-dev libnl-idiag-3-dev`

Comment: I found this answer using the following command to locate the needed packages: `apt-cache search genl-3` typically the "-dev" version of a missing library is what is needed when missing something during a build.

Comment: If anything this should be marked as a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/q/496585 Obviously OP didn't read the full answer that specifically states how to deal with this error.

Comment: Or, also a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/a/391174 as mentioned earlier

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT**

To deal with that particular error install the following packages and try again. Open a terminal and execute the following commands after you cd into the proper directory:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo make clean
sudo apt-get install libnl-genl-3-200 libnl-genl-3-dev libnl-idiag-3-dev
make
sudo make install
```

---

**Short Answer**

You don't need to manually download software you need to install silly, this is debian ubuntu not windows :) why do you think we don't have so many viruses and malware like windows does? It's because of certified package management and debian / ubuntu by far has the largest repo of any other unix like distro.

Open a terminal and execute the following commands to install aricrack-ng

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install aircrack-ng
```

To search for software available through the official ubuntu repositories, you can open the ubuntu software center or you can run the following commands in a similar way described in the following example:

```
apt-cache search aircrack-ng
```

or to limit the results to only those containing the word aircrack, use grep like so:

```
apt-cache search aircrack-ng | grep aircrack
```

Comment: I have edited the question. please check

Comment: @lakksmansritharan I see you've edited the question, this is still the correct answer for installing aricrack. If there is some reason you do not want to install this particular version of aircrack then we can address the issue. Otherwise, you should follow these instructions to install the package. You will need to enable the universe repository. Please post any errors for further assistance.